# WiFi UDP.endPacket() continuously fails

Tags: networking

I am attempting to send data from my Arduino to my computer using the WiFi shield.  However, my code is erroring out on UDP.endPacket(), and I do not understand why.  Here is my code:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUDP.h>

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
char ssid[] = "NETGEAR31"; //  your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "oddearth926";    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)

char  ReplyBuffer[] = "acknowledged";       // a string to send back

WiFiUDP Udp;

void setup()
{
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // check for the presence of the shield:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) 
  {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
    // don't continue:
    while (true);
  }
  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
  printWifiStatus();
  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
  if(!Udp.begin(8765))
  {
    Serial.println(F("failed"));
  }

  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
}

void loop() 
{
  IPAddress ip(10,0,0,5);
  int port = 8766;
    // send a reply, to the IP address and port that sent us the packet we received
    if(!Udp.beginPacket(ip, port))
    {
      Serial.println(F("Failed beginning packet"));
    }
    Udp.print(ReplyBuffer);

    if(!Udp.endPacket())
    {
      Serial.println(F("Failed ending packet")); 
    }
}


void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

And here is the log:

```
Attempting to connect to SSID: NETGEAR31
Connected to wifi
SSID: NETGEAR31
IP Address: 10.0.0.34
signal strength (RSSI):-63 dBm

Starting connection to server...
Failed ending packet
Failed ending packet
Failed ending packet
Failed ending packet
Failed ending packet
Failed ending packet
```

It will continue to spit out "Failed ending packet" until I stop it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by updating firmware on Wifi Shield.